# Xpath matching with wiremock.net

Tags: c#, xpath, wiremock

I am trying to match request body in my wiremock.net mock service and send specific response back, only when
'code' tag contains value of '01.23.45.678.910'.

here is the xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" 
                  xmlns:v1="some-url" 
                  xmlns:com="some-url">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:TestRequest>
         <v1:RequestParameters>
            <com:requestorDN>tst</com:requestorDN>
            <com:requestID>ece8c518-669e-4a17-840b-62ff4c047f04</com:requestID>
            <com:useSoapFaults>1</com:useSoapFaults>
         </v1:RequestParameters>
         <v1:code>01.23.45.678.910</v1:code>
      </v1:TestRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and here is the query, which has no effect:

```
/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:TestRequest/*:code[.='01.23.45.678.910']
```

how can I do this matching correctly?

Comment: I think you need to use `/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*...` etc. if you want to ignore the namespace

Comment: The XML in your example is not "namespace wellformed". It uses namespace prefixes which are not associated with any namespace URI. There are missing namespace declarations for the `soapenv`, `v1`, and `com` prefixes.

Comment: Does this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56779690/3710053

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I think  asterisks('*') provided in my example solves that problem

Comment: If your XPath version can handle that, your XPath should work

Comment: Note that this question refers to [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) which could handle the xpath query differently. I'll take a look...

Comment: turns out the problem was in source code, rather than the matcher or wiremock.  this query //*:code[.='01.23.45.678.910'] as well as the one above worked just fine. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

WireMock's documentation gives an example of how to bind XML namespace prefixes to XML namespace URIs, so that you can write an XPath expression using those namespace prefixes.

https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/

> If you need to be able to select elements based on their namespace in
> addition to their name you can declare the prefix to namespace URI
> mappings and use them in your XPath expression:
>
> Java:

```java
.withRequestBody(matchingXPath("/stuff:outer/more:inner[.=111]")   
.withXPathNamespace("stuff", "http://stuff.example.com")   
.withXPathNamespace("more", "http://more.example.com"))
```

> JSON:

```json
{   "request": {
    ...
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "matchesXPath" : "/stuff:outer/more:inner[.=111]",
      "xPathNamespaces" : {
        "stuff" : "http://stuff.example.com",
        "more"  : "http://more.example.com"
      }
    } ]
    ...   },   ... }
```

Comment: Most XPath APIs do provide some way to declare namespace bindings, and I'd always recommend seeking it out in the documentation, and using it, rather than using `local-name(.)` or similar hacks where you ignore the namespace.

Answer (score -1):

As @Xerillio correctly pointed out you need to use `local-name()` function to ignore namespaces. And to match the xml tag value you can use `text()` function.
You also can take advantage of node selector with wildcard `//*` which selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are .

Following xpath query worked for me :

```
//*[local-name()='v1:code' and text()='01.23.45.678.910']
```

Comment: That will not work. local-name() will not return a namespace-prefix